# Auto incremented value not persist in persistent object after transaction commit until session closed

Tags: hibernate, jpa, transactions, auto-increment, persist

I have Entity with generated "Id" as well as another attribute call "code" with auto incremented value. After call `session.persist(entity)` and `transaction.commit()` the value of "code" in persistant object is null event the DB get updated with value and try to fetch the value from DB in same session getting null value. but with new session the Auto genereted value will fetching to the new persistant object.

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class BaseEntity implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer  id;

    @Column(name = "code")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer code;

    @Column(name = "note")
    private String note;

}
```

```
 @Override
    public Optional<Integer> persist(T entity)
    {
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try{
            transaction=session.beginTransaction();
            session.persist(entity);
            session.flush();
            transaction.commit();
            return Optional.of(entity.getId());
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            if (transaction != null) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
            LOGGER.error(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(throwable));
            throwable.printStackTrace();
        }

        return Optional.empty();
    }
```

Comment: In your code you don't fetch the entity from the database but only access the id with a getter. This will be null of course. I would use JPA repository instead of vanilla Hibernate session. Then you will just need one line: entity = repository.save(entity)